# Rails View Hacking Security

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails 5 app secured by limiting access to certain controller actions/views.

As far as row based security goes, is it possible, within a rails view for an end user to hack it by manipulating the view with something like `Datum.all.pluck(:sensitive_column)` Assuming no params are passed in.

Or is filtering data out in the controller in a where clause enough with something like `where(current_user.id = user_id)`

Answer (score 0):

First off, you probably want to sanitize your query string so that people can't do SQL injection. The [Rails Security Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection) gives a lot of basic info on this.

Instead of thinking about this from the view, think about this from the instance variable you are creating in the controller. Ideally, you'd want to scope that find long before it hits the view.

So in your Datum model, you'd setup your scopes to allow for certain users to access the data, and others not.

If you've got various types of users, an authentication approach like [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) might be more up your alley.